# MySQL : How can I manually increment the values in CURSOR FOR?

Tags: mysql

How can I manually increment the values of `CURSOR FOR`, lets say for example, I have this table:

id | invn_id | qty | remaining_qty | trans_date |
1  |   484   | 163 |       163     | 2014-03-21 |
2  |   230   | 100 |       100     | 2014-03-21 |
3  |   412   | 150 |       150     | 2014-03-21 |

I want to get the first row's `remaining_qty` first, and loop through it until it become `0`. And when it becomes `0`, I'll proceed to the next row where `remaining_qty` is equal to `100`. But the problem is I can't do this process in `CURSOR FOR` since it already `FETCH` all the rows inside. Is there any possibilities to manually increment the values inside the `CURSOR FOR`? So far, I have this code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sample ()
BEGIN
   DECLARE invn_id, row_count, first_col, second_col VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE final_count INT;
   DECLARE col CURSOR FOR SELECT remaining_quantity, invn.trans_date
            FROM invn
            INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id=invn.prod_id
            INNER JOIN bucket_ins bi ON bi.inventory_id=invn.id
            WHERE p.id=(
                SELECT p.id
                FROM invn
                INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id=invn.prod_id
                INNER JOIN bucket_out bo ON bo.inventory_id=invn.id
                WHERE invn.id=406 LIMIT 1
            )
            ORDER BY p.id, invn.trans_date ASC;

   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO row_count
   FROM invn
   INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id=invn.prod_id
   INNER JOIN bucket_ins bi ON bi.inventory_id=invn.id
   WHERE p.id=(
      SELECT p.id
      FROM invn
      INNER JOIN prod p ON p.id=invn.prod_id
      INNER JOIN bucket_out bo ON bo.inventory_id=invn.id
      WHERE invn.id=406 LIMIT 1
    )
    ORDER BY p.id, invn.trans_date ASC;

    OPEN col;
    read_loop : WHILE row_count != 0 DO
    FETCH col INTO first_col, second_col;
       IF first_col <> 0 THEN
          SET first_col = first_col - 1;
          SELECT first_col , second_col;
       ELSEIF first_col = 0 THEN
          SET row_count = row_count - 1;
       END IF;
    END WHILE read_loop;
    CLOSE col;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would put a `while` loop inside the cursor loop.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks! I will try and will get back if I solved it.